# Метод Монте-Карло

Tags: c++

Нужно посчитать вероятность совпадения 2 чисел (похожее парадокс дней рождения) методом Монте-Карло. Вроде делаю правильно, но правильная вероятность не получается, что нужно подправить?

```
int main() {

    int amount;
    int count = 0;
    float experiment;
    cin >> people;
    cin >> experiment;
    int match[people + 1];

    for (int k = 1; k < (people + 1); k++) {
        match[k] = rand() % 365 + 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < (people + 1); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < (people + 1); j++) {
            if (match[i] == match[j]) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Result:" << count / experiment;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как Вы поняли, что вероятность неправильная? Есть ссылка на описание самого метода?

Comment: Надо случайно выбирать двух представителей массива. Не по-порядку

Comment: Монте-Карло предполагает не один эксперимент, а дофига. И общее количество вариантов (experiment) тоже, как и количество подходящих вариантов (count) есть величина счётная, а не свободно-вводимая. Ну и - нафига каждую пару два раза считать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проверил на Dev - работает

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {

    int people,i,j;
    int count = 0;
    float experiment;
    std::cin >> people;
    std::cin >> experiment;
    int birthday[people];
    count = 0;

    for(int n=0;n<experiment;n++){
        // Формируем случайную группу
        for (int k = 0; k < people; k++) {
            birthday[k] = rand() % 365 + 1;
            //std::cout<<birthday[k]<<"\n";
        }
        // Ищем совпадение ДР
        for (i = 0; i < people; i++) 
            for(j=i+1;j<people;j++)
                if (birthday[i] == birthday[j]) {
                    count++;
                    i=people;//Остановка цикла
                    j=people;//проверок совпадений
                }   
    }


    std::cout << "Result:" << count / experiment;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, понял в чем была ошибка:)